MS-Access: Custom ID number does not save back into table
I'm creating a database and a data entry form in MS Access. The custom ID number I have on the form will auto-populate based on certain user entries, as the sample below:
User enters "date of report" (for example, "09/18/2024")
User enters "issue type" (for example, "Carbon")
Auto-populated custom ID is set to generate the following customized ID number:
"Carbon-24-001"
I first created the table for the database with all the fields, including a short text field for the custom ID, then made the form, and within the form, I changed the "control source" of this particular field to produce the ID shown above. The formula I used is:
[IssueTypeTable].[Column](1)&"-"&"Right[Date_of_Report],2)&"-"&Format([ID],"000")
When I test out the form, after the "date of report" and "issue type" fields get filled in, the custom ID auto-populates and shows the right thing on the form. When I save, the entry gets saved to the database. The issue is, but when I open the database table, the custom ID field remains empty.
I instead tried making the custom ID field in the table a "calculated" one and tried using the same formula for source but that wouldn't work. What could I be doing wrong? Really appreciate any help or insight!

When your text box ControlSource is an expression, the control's value does not get saved.  If you want that value saved into a field in the current row of the form's RecordSource, use that field name as the ControlSource.  But then you would need to load the computed text box value some other way --- maybe from the After Update events of the IssueTypeTable and Date_of_Report controls.

Alternative is to save each part of this identifier in separate fields and combine them by expression when needed. Expression as shown has error and could not work. It is missing opening parenthesis for the Right function.

@HansUp Thank you, I have removed the expression from the ControlSource operation.

@June7 , I'm trying this with a test database. Everything works except adding the leading zeros to the ID (when I add the last part "Format([ID],"000")" it says this cannot be added to a calculated field.

Update: overcame the issue with my Access not recognizing the "Format" function by using the "Right" function instead. Thank you both for your help!

Format() function is not available to Calculated type field in table. Do calc in query or textbox.
